# SecKeyEncrypt kSecPaddingNone

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I've been experiencing some frustration when trying to use `SecKeyEncrypt()` with `kSecPaddingNone`. After much investigation, I've found a workaround, but I want to know what's going on. At the moment, I don't have the code available, but I will be able to post it later today. I'm really not convinced that the problem lies in my code, though: I tend to believe that I'm just plain old doing something fundamentally wrong. (That is, I believe my code is right, but that what I'm trying to do is wrong.)

My problem is this: I'd like to encrypt a large block of data using a symmetric key, and then encrypt that key using a different public key. Using `CryptoExercise` as a template, I've fairly easily got a bunch of code that does that. I generate a symmetric key for `AES128`, use it to encrypt my large buffer. My unit tests have no trouble with that.

But then my unit tests create a public/private key pair, attempt to encrypt the symmetric key with the public key, decrypt it with the private key, and then decrypt the large buffer. Note that I've made some simplifying assumptions based on the restricted domain of my problem set: I'm always using `AES128` to encrypt the large buffer, so the key is always 16 bytes, and I'm always using a 1024-bit public/private key pair, so I encrypt the `AES` key by creating a 128-byte buffer, filling it with random data, and then embedding the `AES` key into that buffer.

Finally, since I've got a fixed set of buffer sizes, I'm using `kSecPaddingNone` when I call `SecKeyEncrypt() . My assumption was that I could rely on my method of filling the buffer and knowledge of the buffer sizes.

What I saw when I started running my tests was frustrating: about 80% of the time, they work just fine. But the other 20%, `SecKeyEncrypt()` fails with an `OSStatus` of -50, bad parameter. I spent quite a bit of time looking for stack corruption, heap corruption, premature deallocation, etc., but that was fruitless.

Then I started looking at the public/private key pair operations on just plain old buffers, i.e. I made a new unit test which tried to encrypt/decrypt buffers that I created and filled manually. At this point, I found my clues: if I sent, for example, a zero buffer, then `SecKeyEncrypt` fell into an infinite loop. If I sent a buffer filled with just ones, then it worked fine. And if I filled the buffer with ones, and then replaced the first byte with zero, I got back into an infinite loop.

Various other patterns led me to my workaround, which is presently to insert the AES key *after* the first byte and to always set the first byte to one, but I'm heartily confused. From the documentation for `SecKeyEncrypt()`:

> Typically, `kSecPaddingPKCS1`  is used, which adds `PKCS1` padding before encryption. If you specify `kSecPaddingNone`, the data is encrypted as-is.

The way I read that, the contents of the plaintext buffer should not affect the execution of the encryption algorithm, and yet, my unit tests seem to indicate that it is happening, and that the first byte of the buffer is somehow crucial to the operation. And my workaround seems to pass my unit tests 100% of the time.

Does anybody with more experience here have anything that'd help me understand what's going on? Am I misinterpreting the documentation? Am I trying to do something that I shouldn't be? Did I oversimplify?

I can post the code later tonight, once I have access to it again, if anybody thinks it'll help.

Comment: Why not just use PKCS1 padding? You know it is very dangerous to do raw RSA operations, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use raw RSA encryption, your message *m* (expressed as an integer) has to be less than the modulus *n* of the (public) key (*n*, *e*), otherwise decryption wouldn't be possible, see the description of the [RSA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Encryption):

*c* = *m* ^ *e* (mod *n*)

[Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Padding_schemes) takes care of that, standards such as PKCS#1 have been carefully designed to securely pad messages prior to RSA encryption. If you ask for `kSecPaddingNone` the function assumes you know what you are doing and supply you own padding.

Note that you should **never** use raw RSA encryption, it's always part of a protocol designed to avoid the weaknesses of the algorithm, see "[Attacks against plain RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Attacks_against_plain_RSA)".